# Effects Control does not show anything

Tags: after-effects

When I made a shape, all of my effects like rotation, scale, etc. would pop up in the Effects Control window. Now they don't and I have to work in that cramped space in the timeline. Why is this?

Here's an image of the problem:

[image]

Comment: Learn the keyboard shortcuts, that makes accessing the different properties much easier. And if you want to edit the graphs the button just to the left of the playhead in your picture is the one you want to click.

Answer (score 2):

My AE was always like that. I believe you confusing Adobe After Effects "Effects Control" panel, with Adobe Premiere "Effects Control" panel, where you can find all basic effects.